# Polarisation density at Infinity

Tags: potential, polarization

https://mysite.du.edu/~jcalvert/phys/polariza.htm

Here is a link which gives a short proof on finding the electric potential for a given Polarisation density(**P**).
(*Parragraph 6*)

While deriving, there is an assumption that **P** is 0 at infinity. Could anyone explain to me why this assumption is taken?

Thanks.